# Spectra of rings that are projective module over a subring

Tags: homological-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

This question is motivated from my [last question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4317/integrally-closed-factor-rings-and-projective-modules) here. I wonder if one has a ring A and an over-ring of this ring say B, and if we know that B is a projective A-module can we have a particular idea of how Spec B would look like if we know how Spec A would look like?

This question does make sense to me. Because for instance given a local ring A, then B's are some form of copies of A. If A were zero dimensional reduced and commutative then Spec B would look like copies of clopen subsets of Spec A (because projective modules over von Neumann regular rings are isomorphic to direct sum of principal ideals). So what else do we know?

Comment: Is B finitely generated over A?

Comment: Initially we could assume this to be so. But for the results i mentioned they need not be (modules over local rings being free or over von Neumann regular rings being direct sums of principal ideals is a general case)..except the word "copies" may not be appropriate for infinitely generated case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, for example, A could be a field k, and B could be any k-algebra whatsoever.  Basically you would be trying to recover all of classical algebraic geometry from Spec k.  It does not seem likely.

Comment: Well, if we have Spec k as a scheme, we still have k by taking global sections of the structure sheaf, so we at least know what a K-algebra looks like, but "B is a k-algebra" doesn't give us much information about spec B.  Agreeing with you, but clarifying for the questioner.

Comment: Yep, I agree too. Thanks. That pretty much wraps it! :)